# Elixir can't find get/2 function in page_controller_test.exs

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I get an error that says cant find get/2 function, this is in the test created when you create a new elixir project, I have only changed it to the ExUnit test.
What am I doing wrong?

```
use ExUnit.Case

test "GET /", %{conn: conn} do
  conn = get conn, "/"
  assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "Welcome to Phoenix"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are trying to use ([`get/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#get/3)) comes from [`Phoenix.ConnTest`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#content), which you get by using the generated `ProjectName.ConnCase` module. So changing

```
use ExUnit.Case
```

to

```
use ProjectName.ConnCase
```

may help.

If it does not work you can try to directly use `Phoenix.ConnTest`. That is:

```
use ExUnit.Case
use Phoenix.ConnTest
```

Comment: See I did that but it could never find the module. I have them both in app_web, the controller test being in /controller as well and i match the names and it still doesnt work so thats why i switched to exunit

Comment: You could also try `Phoenix.ConnTest` directly. Something like `use ExUnit.Case; use Phoenix.ConnTest`.

Comment: Thank you that gets it to work. If you could edit your post to include the Phoenix.ConnTest and the Exunit.case I will approve your answer as it now correctly runs the tests

Comment: Sure thing. Just a sec. :)